# how to change color of sphere in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

how to change color of sphere in matlab my code for plotting sphere is

```
figure;
plotOnSphere(Xem,Yem,Zem);


%// Plot a unit sphere for reference
sphere()
s = findall(gca, 'type', 'surf');
set(s, 'FaceColor', 'k', 'FaceAlpha', 0.01, 'EdgeAlpha', 0.1)
```

[image: sphere]

my question is that i want to get the plot of the sphere with only lines and not these colors attached to the spherical sections .
can someone please help me.

```
function plotOnSphere(x,y,z,varargin)

    %// Vectors representing each point
    xyz = [x(:), y(:), z(:)].';  %'

    %// One vector of the "first" points and one of the "next" points
    v1 = xyz(:, 1:end-1);
    v2 = xyz(:, 2:end);

    %// Cross product between the vectors of one point and the next
    cv1v2 = cross(v1, v2);

    %// Compute unit vector in the plane defined by v1 and v2
    v3 = normc(cross(cv1v2, v1));

    %// Figure out the range of the inner angle between v1 and v2
    nc = sqrt(sum(cv1v2.^2, 1));
    t = atan2(nc, dot(v1, v2, 1));

    %// Number of points to sample between any two points on the sphere
    nPoints = 100;

    %// Compute the interpolant
    V = zeros([nPoints, fliplr(size(v1))]);
    for k = 1:numel(t)
        T = linspace(0, t(k), 100);
        V(:,k,:) = (v1(:,k) * cos(T) + v3(:,k) * sin(T)).';    %'
    end

    %// Break the result out into x,y,z parts
    xx = V(:,:,1);
    yy = V(:,:,2);
    zz = V(:,:,3);

    %// Plot the lines
    h = plot3(xx(:), yy(:), zz(:), varargin{:});
    hold on

    %// Plot the original data points
    plot3(x,y,z, 'o', ...
        'Color', get(h, 'Color'), ...
        'Parent', get(h, 'Parent'), varargin{:});
end
```

Comment: Your code does produce a nearly transparent sphere.. there must be something else to your problem.

Comment: Please post the code of `plotOnSphere()`, that's probably where your problem is.

Comment: Try using [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) instead of `plot3`.